# Apache 2.4: combine dbd and mod_auth_form, how to encrypt the passwords?

Tags: apache-2.4

If I'm using mod_auth_form and the dbd backend, how am I supposed to encrypt the passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/misc/password_encryptions.html) discusses the various password formats supported by Apache.  Reading through the [mod_auth_form](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_auth_form.html) documentation and the [mod_auth_dbd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html) documentation, it strongly suggests that any of these formats should be acceptable.